# Indexpath stored in array behaves differently

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsindexpath

I m trying to store selected indexpaths for some purpose. Below code I m executing in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:`

```
 if ([_arrOfIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [filterCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [filterCell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:filterCell.textLabel.font.pointSize]];
    }
```

When I m trying to print the description following line gets printed.

```
<__NSArrayM 0x91567d0>(
<NSIndexPath: 0x8e8b5b0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0},
<NSIndexPath: 0x91559a0> {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}
)
Printing description of indexPath:
<NSIndexPath: 0x91a8460> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

If you see the instance description **0x91a8460** which is not available in the array. 
But still condition succeeded. Could some one explain me how this works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the docs for the `containsObject:` method. The objects are compared with a call to `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 1):

Instance `0x91a8460` is not present in the array, but path `0-0` is. Comparison for `containsObject:` is performed by `isEqual`, not by object identity. If you want an object-identity comparison, use `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is not ideal to store `indexPath`(s) in an array then use it to update table cell. It maybe better to use array of dictionary where you have all your table data there, then you can add a key like `isCheck` and set it `TRUE` or `FALSE` after user action.

Or

You can still have your array but instead of storing the indexpath better make a string combination like `(@"%d%d",indexpath.row, indexpath.section)` and use it to string compare.

Hope that helps.